# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

hello I try to create register in laravel 5.8 but when i try to register have this error :

tableuser.php

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

registe.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (denden73, denden73@gmail.com,
>   $2y$10$x.J7316.UH.UFnzZaeI5F.TTXkYyd.xVUlrjV6EoHA7J88R0X9Ode,
>   2019-07-25 12:50:54, 2019-07-25 12:50:54))

Comment: Have you updated your controller so that it stores the username?

Comment: Possibly, you have no 'username' in your  'fillable' array in model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this to your User.php model file

```
protected fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've followed this rule or not.

1) use nullable() while migrate.

-> **It becuase of when you are inserting any record and if the field value is not set then this error would occur.**

```
$table->string('username')->nullable();
```

2) Fillable in your model.

-> **IF you didn't set nullable as a column, Now while inserting record you tried to insert value but if that value is not fillable in the model then it'll not insert so it this error would occur.**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'name', 'email','password','admin'
];
```

3) mention the username while creating a new user.

-> **Sometime by mistake you're not passing that value while creating so if that field is not null in MySQL then this erro would occur.**

```
$user = new App\User;
$user->username = 'xyz';
$user->save();
```

Comment: great start dilip, it is nice to follow the standard, I see your solution clean, informative and well written

Comment: Thank you very much. Happy to help.

Comment: why are you changing from `->unique()` to `->nullable()`? this could cause problems, e.g. having usernames multiple times in the db when you would expect this field to be unique.
Of course, this solves the problem of the failing query, but in my opinion opens up another box...

Answer (score -6):

Your insert query like:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(array('username'=>$request->username,'name'=>$request->name,'email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password));
```

Comment: there's a problem with the table definition and the way it is accessed by the ORM, changing an insert statement (that is probably not even called by the user) won't help in this instance

Comment: And it is always better to explain what was the problem and why your solution is suggested.

Comment: You should write more than "try this" on your answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!